# Remove unwanted columns Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

The table I have is like this:

```
CEID  BUID   WEIGHT TREND SCORE Quarter
---------------------------------------
CE001 BU001    4     5     20     1
CE001 BU001    4     0     22     2
CE001 BU001    4     0     23     3
CE001 BU001    4     0     24     4
```

The result I want is like this

```
CEID  BUID   WEIGHT TREND Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
---------------------------------------
CE001 BU001    4      NA  20 22 23 24
```

I wrote the following Pivot query:

```
select * 
from table
pivot (sum (score) for quarter in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as ScorePerQuarter
```

But since trend is also changing I am getting multiple rows in Pivoted query as well..for different values of trend..

How can I achieve the result shown above? ie: remove trend column from the query altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stop using SELECT * against the main table, and leave out the TREND column:

```
;WITH t AS
(
  select CEID, BUID, WEIGHT, SCORE, Quarter from dbo.table
)
SELECT * FROM t
pivot (sum (score) for quarter in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as ScorePerQuarter;
```

If you want `TREND = NA` as shown in your "result i want", just hard-code it:

```
;WITH t AS
(
  select CEID, BUID, WEIGHT, TREND = 'NA', SCORE, Quarter from dbo.table
)
SELECT * FROM t
pivot (sum (score) for quarter in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as ScorePerQuarter;
```

Comment: Thanks.. So a temporary table is needed.

Comment: @eyeanand no, there is no temporary table here. That is a common table expression (CTE). You could also do it with a subquery / derived table.

Comment: ok..but isn't a CTE a sort of temporary storage which goes off as soon as its use is over.... i got the idea for the query...also i wanted to insert the query result into a table so there the CTE syntax was creating problems hence i created a temp table and used pivot on that table...anyways i got the idea you shared.

Comment: If you want to insert the results of a CTE into another table, just do `;WITH t AS (some query) INSERT dbo.table(cols) SELECT cols FROM t;`